# ESP01-Apache server send data with Post to .php file

Tags: php, apache, esp8266, at-command

So basically I am trying to send data to a textfile in raspberrypi(apache server) from my ESP01 using AT-Commands.
I am trying to use POST method of apache for same.
Here is my PHP code:

```
`<?php
$tempF=$_POST["temp"];
$file='testfile.text';
$myfile=($file,"w+");
fwrite($myfile,$tempF);
fclose($myfile);
?>`
```

Here is the data I send through AT Command (AT+CIPSEND)

```
`POST /TEMP/post.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.0.138:80\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length:9 \r\n\r\ntemp=1234`
```

So when I send this AT command, I assume that php file should be executed and data from 'temp' variable should be written to the text file. However there is no such output visible nor any errors displayed.

Here is simple map of how paths are placed
root folder:/var/www/html
inside it -> TEMP(folder), index.html
inside TEMP -> post.php, testfile.txt

I have already tried following :

1. Replace the $tempF variable with text and execute PHP on raspberrypi. So I conclude that there is no issue in php code since it worked great.
2. Enabled php mod and simple php index file works too.
   3)Tried changing all possible pathways.
   4)Give complete permissions to all files to read, write and execute in root folder. i.e index.html, post.php and testfile.txt

[Screenshot of my at commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErVTV.png)

P.S.
I am new to PHP and POST method of HTTP/1.1

Thanks☻

EDIT 1: As from Juraj's comment I realised that when you send \r\n through serial monitor it actually sends \n and so I tried the conventional method while entering Post Command as follows:

```
POST /TEMP/post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.138:80
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length:9

temp=1234
```

And I recieved following Error:

```
 +IPD,187:HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
 Date: Fri, 06 Aug 2021 13:06:57 GMT
 Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Raspbian)
 Content-Length: 0
 Connection: close
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Update:

While searching for same, I found reqbin.com which helps to test POST/GET methods too and I still got same error 500.
Note:My timeout currently is 120000ms and all files are given full permissions.

Comment: what code does send the AT commands?

Comment: Am editing and uploading screenshot

Comment: Serial Monitor doesn't translate \r\n to line endings required in HTTP protocol

Comment: Sorry I had mistake in CIPSEND LENGTH  so have updated the screenshot with new fresh commands.(Issue will still remain)
Besides I have both NL and CR on in serial monitors newline interface option . So I just need \r\n on the chunk of data that is to be send.

Comment: If I dont use \r\n and use traditional way to hit enter ainstead of \r\n in the data chunk, I get error 500

Comment: you can"t enter the lines fast enough

Comment: hmmm, Is there anyway to enter lines fast enough trough serial monitor ?

Comment: I tried to increase timeout of apache but it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you extract details about the 500 error from the Apache log?

Comment: And maybe try `tcpdump -n -i any -A 'port 80'` on the server to log what is actually received

Comment: Thankyou so much, Sorry for replying late,(due to some personal issues.) I have checked the log and found out that php file in my raspberry pi had an error while saving. I got confused in brackets and put wrong brackets in my php file stored in pi although code here was correct. Thanks again for your help.